# Name Error for function argument in Tkinter Python Program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, nameerror

I am trying to build a Tkinter GUI for my code that returns the least amount of coins needed given an
amount. I used a lambda function for my code because I know you can't pass arguments with Tkinter.

I apologize in advance for the long code guys. I spent hours on it and couldn't find out what to do to fix it. I appreciate any help or advice you can give me.

Here is the error Im getting and then there is my code:

```
NameError: name 'stack' is not defined
```

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial




#Given a number of cents, return the least number of coins that sums to that amount



def solve(cents):
    stack = []
    result = 0
    quarter = 25
    dime = 10
    nickel = 5
    penny = 1
    difference = abs(cents - result)
    
    if cents == 25:
            result += quarter
            return stack.append("25")
    if cents == 10:
            result += dime
            return stack.append("10")
    if cents == 5:
            result += nickel
            return stack.append("5")
    if cents == 1:
            result += penny
            return stack.append("1")
            
    while cents != result:
        
        while difference >= quarter:
                result += quarter
                stack.append("25")
                difference = abs(cents - result)

            
        while difference >= dime and difference < quarter:
            result += dime
            stack.append("10")
            difference = abs(cents - result)

            
        while difference >= nickel and difference < dime:
            result += nickel
            stack.append("5")
            difference = abs(cents - result)

            
        while difference >= penny and difference < nickel:
            result += penny
            stack.append("1")
            difference = abs(cents - result)
            
        newResult = print(stack)
        return newResult
```

```
def print(stack):       
    Quarter = 0
    Dime = 0
    Nickel = 0
    Penny = 0
    for num in stack:
        if num == "1":
            Penny += 1
        elif num == "5":
            Nickel += 1
        elif num == "10":
            Dime += 1
        elif num == "25":
            Quarter += 1
    return f"Minimum coins required are: {Quarter} Quarters, {Dime} Dimes, {Nickel} Nickels, {Penny} Pennies "
         
    

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Minimum Coins Needed')
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text= "Click Calculate to see the Result")
canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label1)

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

button1 = tk.Button(text='Calculate',command= lambda: print(stack))
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)
button1.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: To solve just simply put `stack = []` outside of the funcitons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve just simply put

```py
stack = []
```

outside of the functions somewhere at the beginning of the code or in this case could do like this:

```py
stack = []
def solve():
    # the rest of the code
```

The issue is that You define it inside the function which means the variable is local to that function thus cannot be accessed by other functions (other options is to use `global` I guess but I am not sure how exactly, maybe that is even not the way here)

Also as @Fred mentioned don't use `print` as a function name since it is already a built-in.

Also a bigger issue would be that now although it won't throw any errors because it works it won't do anything much since it is quite pointless to return a value from a function if that function is used in `command` argument for a Button since You can't get to that returned value.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! I also used a print statement instead of return and that outputted my desired result.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is this line,

```
button1 = tk.Button(text='Calculate',command= lambda: print(stack))
```

stack variable is not defined, but in your function print (warning, print is a function built-in python, don't use this name of function).

EDIT:

> `return stack.append(...)`

the value return is `None`

```
>>> s = []
>>> print(s.append("test"))
None
```

Test in your interpreter python.

Comment: this is not an answer, You just stated what OP already knew without solving the issue (except maybe for that print which I agree shouldn't be used and return stuff but not really because it would actually just execute the appending part and then stop the function so nothing wrong with that either)

Comment: @Fred Thank for the advice to change my function name!